# Do I need to wrap my input field in a form if it's just a search function?

Tags: html, forms, input, accessibility

I just noticed that even Google doesn't use a form to wrap their input fields. I thought this was bad in terms of accessibility because screen readers then won't know what it is?

Comment: If the search is querying the server for some piece of info, then use a form or ajax. Seen here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp and https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a pure screen reader perspective, having a `<form>` is a way to group a set of controls together and works best if you specify a label for the form, such as `<form aria-label="contact info">`.

If you have a simple search field, and presumably an associated search button, then a `<form>` isn't necessarily needed.  However, you **should** nest your elements in a search landmark by using [`role="search"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#search).

```
<div role="search">
  <input aria-label="search term">
  <button aria-label="search">
    <i class="magnifier"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

It looks like the literal, "search", appears a lot in that code fragment, but the only time "search" has to appear literally is the `role` attribute.

The `aria-label` for the input can be whatever string you want.  It's what will be read by the screen reader when focus moves to the field.  If you have a `<label>` for your `<input>`, then the `aria-label` is not needed.

The `<button>` just has a magnifier icon and no text so it will require an `aria-label` too, for the screen reader.  If your icon were an `<img>` instead of an `<i>`, you could specify the button's label in the img's `alt` attribute, in which case the `<button>` wouldn't need an `aria-label`.

```
<div role="search">
  <label for="findit">search term</label>
  <input id="findit">
  <button>
    <img src="magnifier.jpg" alt="search">
  </button>
</div>
```

So the simple answer is, "no", you don't have to put your search in a `<form>`.  But it is strongly encouraged to wrap it in a "search" landmark by using `role="search"`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to but you should always use form tag for any kind of data submission from form elements and google also does (you'll find, if you traverse up in DOM).

Though, you can submit data using AJAX, but not when JavaScript is not running.